# how do I count the number of brackets in a string in a Java regex

Tags: java, regex

So I'm trying to count the number of parentheses (e.g. close brackets) in a string by using a regex. I found this method "groupCount" on the matcher class. So I thought this could help me out.

groupCount says in the JavaDoc "Any non-negative integer smaller than or equal to the value returned by this method is guaranteed to be a valid group index for this matcher." So I'd imagine that the statement

```
m.group(m.groupCount());
```

should always work. Wrong...

Here's some test code I wrote:

```
public class TestJavaBracketPattern {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\))").matcher(")");
        System.out.println(m.group(m.groupCount()));
    }

}
```

Now here I'm expecting to match a close bracket (called \) in regex) and get a single match. The regular expression is (\)) - this should match a group containing the closed bracket symbol. But it just throws some exception (java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found).

Next, I tried matching where there is no match:

```
public class TestJavaBracketPattern {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\))").matcher("(");
        System.out.println(m.group(m.groupCount()));
    }

}
```

I get the same exception. In fact, in both cases I found the groupCount method returns 1.

Very confused.

Comment: The documentation is quite clear on this. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#groupCount()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the below too pragmatic?

```
@Test
void testCountBrackets() {
    String s = "Hello) how)are)you(";
    System.out.println( s.length() - s.replaceAll("\\)", "").length() ); // 3
}
```

(Of course, this assumes that you want to search for a real RE something more complex than just a bracket. Otherwise just use `s.replace(")","")`)

Comment: actually, that's the most elegant thing I've seen all year

Comment: It's not a failure... I tried running it and it reports success (not failure) every time!! ;-)

Comment: `assertEquals(3, s.replaceAll("[^\\)]", "").length());` is even shorter. Enough now. Back to work :-)

Answer (score 1):

groupCount returns the number of groups in the pattern, not in the matched result.

You will have to do something like this;

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\))").matcher("Hello) how)are)you(");
int count = 0;
while (m.find()) {
    count++;
}
System.err.format("Found %1$s matches\n", count);
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't really begin search, it's the reason that exception occurs.

Matcher.groupCount() returns how many groups in Pattern, not the result.

Matcher.group() returns the input subsequence captured by the given group during previous match.

You can refer [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28%29).

I change your code like this,

```
public class TestJavaBracketPattern {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\))").matcher(")");
       if (m.find()) {           
         System.out.println(m.group(m.groupCount()));
       }
    }
}
```

Adding m.find(), and The results is:

```
1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code.

`int count1 = StringUtils.countMatches("fi(n)d ( i)n ( the st)(ri)ng", "(")`; // for '('

`int count2 = StringUtils.countMatches("fi(n)d ( i)n ( the st)(ri)ng", ")")`; // for ')'

```
int totalCount = count1+count2;
```

`StringUtils` is present in `common-lang` library.